# How to Add Images to Elements Within a Linked List

Tags: java, image, linked-list, point

I'm creating the game Snake. I have defined the snake as a linked list which will hold the individual within an element. I want to set each individual bit to have an image I have created with dimensions (20, 20) and in jpeg format. I have placed the image into the src foldr in which I have created a resource folder, this is where the image is held.

This is the method in which I am using to set this image. I am unsure how to set the image within this. The method will be called to draw the snake.

```
//This is a method used to set the image for the snake bits.
    public void imgSnake() {
        //A for loop which will assign every point on the snake linked list to have this image.
        for (Point p : snake) {
             //This is where I need to set the image
        }
```

Comment: why do you need set image? just draw it!

Comment: Would it be possible to draw an image with a border of width 2 pixels? The idea was to have an image which has a black outline filled with green to represent the bits. This is a game made for primary school children, trying to make it as fun as possible.

Comment: look at `JComponent.paint` method.